# append and replace content to different elements background-img property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the first instance of a specific div content, which is an image. And then I want to append this image content to the `background property` of a second element *(to appear as background image content)*, is this possible with jQuery?

I'd preferably also like it to replace an existing background image content from the second div element if one exists. Then of course if it doesn't exist it would be creating it and populating it with image content of div element 1.

```
$('.element1').find('img:first').appendTo('.element2');
```

Comment: Yep, that's all possible. The code you have provided however isn't even remotely close.

Comment: Appreciate that @KevinB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your HTML structure looks like:

```
<div class="element1">
  <img />
</div>
<div class="element2">
</div>
```

What you're looking for is:

```
var getImageSrc = $('.element1 img').attr('src');
$('.element2').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');
```

I've created a fiddle showing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/Lbc0dc5p/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: ...Why the downvote? This does exactly what the qustion asker asked for.

Comment: Not sure, but I upvoted you back. Thanks for taking a look at my Q!

Comment: @CamC. -- No problems; hopefully it's what you're looking for :)

Comment: It's not, but it's a help!